# Django : defining method inside the models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

serialize() method included in the django Tools_booked class but while trying to access that method it shows error.

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
class UpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        print("*****Entered the serizlize inside the  UpdateQuerySet models **********")
        qs = self
        return serialize('json', qs, fields=('auto_increment_id','user','component','booked'))

class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class Tools_booked(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    booked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

    objects = UpdateManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.component

    def serialize(self):
        json_data = serialize("json", [self], fields=['auto_increment_id','user','component','booked'])
        stuct = json.loads(json_data)
        print(struct)
        data = json.dump(stuct[0]['fields'])
        return data
```

**views.py**

```
class SerializedDetialView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("*****Entered the SerializedDetialView **********")
        obj_list= Tools_booked.objects.filter(auto_increment_id=1)
        json_data = obj_list.serialize()
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')


class SerializedListView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        json_data = Tools_booked.objects.all().serialize()
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

The error traceback

```
 json_data = Tools_booked.objects.all().serialize()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

But this works.

```
class SerializedDetialView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj_list= Tools_booked.objects.filter(auto_increment_id=1)
        json_data = serializers.serialize("json", obj_list )
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')


class SerializedListView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Tools_booked.objects.all()
        json_data = serializers.serialize("json", qs )
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

How to use the serialize() method inside the models.py ,Tools_booked class.

Comment: use `super()` method

Comment: please share your serializer code

Comment: @Wariored Where to add super()

Comment: @abhikumar22 Hey I am learning Django REST API, at this point my app don't have any serializers.py code. Currently trying to serialize the object query using the method defined inside the models. Previously it worked with in the view.

Comment: @Wariored what does it has to do with `super()` ???

Comment: @VAsplash there's no visible reason you should get this error. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Why you are not using Django rest serializers? They will make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use Django-rest frameworks serializers with `many=True` or use `values()` function of Django queryset. There is no need to write a function in models. It will work like this

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = "You Model Here"
        fields = "write list of your model fields here or user __all__ for all fields"
```

you can serialize your query like this

```
queryset = Your_Model.objects.all()
serialized = YourSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

Other way to do so is like this

```
serialized = Your_Model.objects.all().values()
```

This method look simple but if you are writing rest apis, you should use serializers. You can look into details of serializer [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's working for me:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.db import models


class UpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        print("*****Entered the serizlize inside the  UpdateQuerySet models **********")
        return serialize('json', self, fields=('component','booked'))

class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
      # define here methods only needed inside this manager
       pass 

class Tools_booked(models.Model):
    component = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    booked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    serializer = UpdateManager.from_queryset(UpdateQuerySet)()
```

Now you can do in your views:

```
json_data = Tools_booked.serializer.serialize()
```

I guess you have an error because your `serialize` method is not defined inside the manager

Answer (score 0):

In your models

```
class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, self._db)

    # Here for you to call to your views
    def serialize(self):
        return self.get_queryset().serialize()
```

In your views

```
json_data = Tools_booked.objects.all().serialize()
```

Django has changed a little bit.
Here is [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/) for Django update version.